# Error in Package-Bits in Vapor

Tags: swift, vapor

When I'm trying to run Vapor from Xcode, it shows me an error:

> /Users/apple/HelloWorld/Packages/Bits-1.0.0/Sources/Bits/ByteSequence+Conversions.swift:9:16:
>
> Value of type '[Byte]' has no member 'withUnsafeBytes'

Im using

**Vapor - 2.0.3**

**Xcode - 8.2.1**

**Snapshot used: Swift 3.0 GM CANDIDATE Snapshot 2016-09-08 (a)**

Comment: Are you able to use an official release version of Swift 3.0 or 3.1?

Comment: 3.0 i have used

Comment: What about 3.1? And in case I wasn’t clear earlier, I did mean a release, not a GM candidate as you described in the question.

Comment: Im getting swift 3.0 when i try "swift --version" from terminal

Answer (score 2):

Vapor 2 requires Swift 3.1, so you should upgrade your version of Xcode to get the latest version of Swift

Comment: Unable to update XCode my system is Early 2008. Ei capitan 10.11.6.

Comment: Ah...this will present a problem. You will have to stick with Vapor 1 then. You may have some success installing a 3.1 toolchain into Xcode 8.2 but this would be entirely experimental and unsupported

Comment: will vapor 1 have the support for swift 3.1 anyway?

Comment: Vapor 1 works with Swift 3.0 and 3.1 fine. Vapor 2 requires Swift 3.1 

Comment: At last, out of question. what i need to add in "brew install vapor" for installing vapor 1

Comment: I _think_ it is just `brew install vapor1`